# Retrofit 2 Close ErrorResponse Body

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2.

> When i receive an unsuccessful response do i have to close manually
>   the erroBody();

```
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    // Success
} else {
    response.errorBody().close(); ???????????????????
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. There's no need to call `response.errorBody().close()`, during an unsuccessful response. In the same way, there's no need to call `response.raw().close();` during a successful response.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call,
                                   @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // successful response from server: HTTP status code is between 200 and 300
                    // log user in, etc
                } else {
                    // unsuccessful response from server: HTTP status code is not between 200 and 300
                    // show toast, call onBackPressed(), etc
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                // network exception occurred while talking to the server
                // or an unexpected exception occurred while creating the request or processing the response

                // Log.d(...);
            }
        });
```